# Microsoft Graph API Accessing basic info of a user that is outside tenancy

Tags: oauth, ms-office, exchangewebservices, multi-tenant, azure-active-directory

I am developing a multi-tenant web app managing the mail, contacts and calendar of users.

On the AzureAd management portal, I registered my app as multi-tenant and I manage to get OAuth tokens for both people out and inside my tenancy, replacing the tennantId by "common" when querying the Authentication Code and Token endpoints.

Now, I would like to access calendar, mail and contacts info of people who signed in and consented to give permissions to my app.

I started simple, by querying the basic user info of a user **inside tenancy** like this:

GET https://graph.windows.net/-tennantId-/me?api-version=2013-11-08
or 
GET https://graph.windows.net/-tennantId-/users/myAdress@company.com?api-version=2013-11-08
{headers: {Authorization: "Bearer -accessToken-"}}

It works!

Now, how can I have access to information of users that are **outside** my tenancy? I tried

GET https://graph.windows.net/-tennantId-/me?api-version=2013-11-08

GET https://graph.windows.net/-tennantId-/users/address@outside.com?api-version=2013-11-08

GET https://graph.windows.net/common/me?api-version=2013-11-08

GET https://graph.windows.net/common/users/address@outside.com?api-version=2013-11-08,

I always end-up having a 400 error:
{"odata.error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Invalid domain name in the request url."}}}

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah-ah!

Forget the use of your tenant ID when talking with the Graph API if you develop a multi-tenant app with OAuth!

The equivalent to "common" when requesting a token for a user in or outside your tenancy is... "myorganization"!

This will work:

https://graph.windows.net/myorganisation/me?api-version=2013-11-08

Oh, it was clearly [written in the doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn424880.aspx), but... but... MICROSOOOOOFT!!!

Comment: Wow I cannot thank you enough. In this Microsoft sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web In the Web.config, I changed this key to: <add key="ida:TenantId" value="myorganization" /> and it worked.

Comment: But what if I want to query in another tenant (that I of course have access to and have admin privileges to in the portal), but isn't the direct one for my user account?

Comment: 2017 Detail -    **Invalid domain name in the request url.**      If you are seeing this error for the classic Graph call ( https://graph.windows.net/ )  then follow this posts advice and switch guid for tenant name.   I have some tenants that need guids and some tenants that need names.  It is possible that old and new tenants behave differently but the name is the “right way” from what I have seen.