# MSC delegated admin and impersonations

Tags: office365, exchange-server, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices, azure-ad-graph-api

I have an MCSP account with admin delegation privileges for my client 365 tenants
i have 2 questions:

1. I would like to be able to get list of accounts in tenant using graph API is it possible?
2. I'm using EWS with impersonation to access mailboxes data, is it possible to use my account with  delegated privileges or should i add service account within the tenant

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to get list of accounts in tenant using graph API, you should add your account to  guest user.

   You could reference this link to add a guest user:

   [Office 365: How to add a guest user from the new Azure AD Portal!](https://regarding365.com/office-365-how-to-add-a-guest-user-from-the-new-azure-ad-portal-ca626f1ffc42)
2. You could use your account with delegated privileges.

   You could reference this link:

   [Using Exchange Impersonation in Exchange 2010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/bb204088(v=exchg.140))

Comment: I'm not sure you got my question, as using same delegated admin account , I want to get list of accounts from different tenants. So, usually, if it's not delegated admin, the email address of the accounts (domain) is used to get list of accounts from this domain, but with delegated admin cross tenants it's not clear.

Comment: May be my expressed has wrong.
About the first question, You could refer to this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811188/microsoft-graph-api-accessing-basic-info-of-a-user-that-is-outside-tenancy
About the second question, you should impersonation the Account if you want to get the account data.